# Angular Proper way to cache or load http requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, caching

This is really more of a question. I am using several http requests in my application that spans an entire site really.

1. Is it better to cache the request or is there a more efficient manner to only make the request on given URL's?
2. Am I understanding the cache method correctly (see below code)

```js
homeApp.controller('mainMenu', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get("http://localhost:3000/wp-json/menus/2", {
    cache: true
  }).then(function(response) {
    $scope.menuData.data = response.data.items;
  });
});
```

I am trying to keep this thing as quick and agile as possible. Thanks all!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could probably customise the HTTP provider to look for certain paths and cache them for your application. But I think coding the specific calls you want cached by specifying `cache=true` is better and clearer?
2. I think you have understood it correctly.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http

"When caching is enabled, $http stores the response from the server using the relevant cache object. The next time the same request is made, the response is returned from the cache without sending a request to the server."

So if you repeatedly make requests to `/wp-json/menus/2` within the scope of an instance of your angular SPA, it will not hit the server. Its quite efficient.

I hope this helps.

Comment: It does! I think really the cache is the solution I was looking for. I am a fan of elegant and simple. I think this is great! lol still just learning the insides and out of angularjs syntax.